# TinyTree.getNamespaceBindings() failing

Tags: saxon

We have upgraded from Saxon EE 9 to 10.1. The following line of code:

```
    private void declareNameSpaces(XdmNode xmlRootNode, XPathCompiler xPath) {
        NamespaceBinding[] namespaceBindings = ((TinyDocumentImpl) xmlRootNode.getUnderlyingValue()).getTree().getNamespaceBindings();

Throws the exception:

    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyTree.getNamespaceBindings(TinyTree.java:1642)
        at net.windward.datasource.xml.SaxonDataSource.declareNameSpaces(SaxonDataSource.java:395)

What do we need to do differently?

The entire code in case you need it is:

private void declareNameSpaces(XdmNode xmlRootNode, XPathCompiler xPath) {
    NamespaceBinding[] namespaceBindings = ((TinyDocumentImpl) xmlRootNode.getUnderlyingValue()).getTree().getNamespaceBindings();

    List<String> prefixes = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (NamespaceBinding namespaceBinding : namespaceBindings) {
        if (namespaceBinding == null)
            break;
        String prefix = namespaceBinding.getPrefix();
        if (prefix == null || prefix.isEmpty()) {//use default prefix if prefix is empty.
            prefix = defaultPrefix;

            // make sure the prefix is unique
            while (prefixes.contains(prefix)) {
                if (Character.isDigit(prefix.charAt(prefix.length() - 1)))
                    prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1) + String.valueOf((int) prefix.charAt(prefix.length() - 1) + 1);
                else
                    prefix = prefix + '1';
            }
            prefixes.add(prefix);
        }
        String uri = namespaceBinding.getURI();
        if (uri != null && !uri.isEmpty()) {
            xPath.declareNamespace(prefix, namespaceBinding.getURI());
            prefixNamespaceMap.put(prefix, namespaceBinding);
            uriToPrifixeMap.put(namespaceBinding.getURI(), prefix);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using what we class as "system programming interfaces" here, which are subject to change from one major release to another. The whole area of namespace representation on the NodeInfo interface changed significantly in 10.0 - see the "changes" section of the documentation for more detail. The model is now closer to the XDM spec, revealing only the in-scope namespaces for a node, and not the "declarations" (i.e. differences from a parent node).

I can't really tell what your code is trying to achieve, especially as it seems to be looking at the namespace bindings for a document node, which will always be empty.

In general with 10.0 you should get namespace information using `NamespaceMap getAllNamespaces();`

Comment: Hi Michael; Sorry, somehow it wasn't displaying all the code. Fixed that. The purpose of this code is to walk through All the nodes in an XML document we just loaded, find all the namespace declarations, and save them off in two maps. One for prefix -> uri and one for uri -> prefix. This is needed to implement NamespaceContext which Saxon needs in places. It looks like getAllNamespaces() gets us all this without our walking the code which is nice. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I tried XdmNode.getUnderlyingNode().getAllNamespaces() but that only returns namespaces declared in the root node. How do we get all namespaces declared throughout the document? Is there a way to match what I'm guessing getTree() did in the old code and get any used anywhere in the XML file?

Comment: I don't think there was ever any way to get all namespaces declared anywhere in the document, other than `//namespace::*`

Comment: Maybe I'm approaching this wrong then. Here's the problem, if we have XML that has namespaces then the XPath has to be /w:document/w:body. Now the namespace xmlns:w is definded at the top of the XML, but as I understand it, I still have to define the namespace mapping for w for the XPath evaluate - correct? Is there a better way to define all the namespaces? Or do I need to read them all out to then pass the mappings in?

Comment: Can you please add a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040489/how-to-read-namespace-from-tags-using-xdmnode in your answer? That has the code to implement this. TIA